# The chart list is not showing

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

This is my chart code

```
        datasets: [
      {
        label: "Fraction KG",
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
          "rgba(200, 121, 121, 0.2)",
        ],
      },
    ],
    labels: label
```

And this is how my chart looks:
[image]

Why is not the list beside the chart not showing is there some option value yu have to set?

[image]

this is the pie component

PieChart.js

```
import { Pie, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
import globalOptionsMixin from "./globalOptionsMixin";
 export default {
  name: 'pie-chart',
  extends: Pie,
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp, globalOptionsMixin],
  props: {
    extraOptions: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
   },
  data() {
     return {
       ctx: null
     };
   },
   mounted() {
    this.$watch(
      'chartData',
      (newVal, oldVal) => {
        if (!oldVal) {
          debugger;
          this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.extraOptions);
        }
      },
      { immediate: true }
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The ChartJs labels are determined by the `labels` property.  In your example, this is set to an unknown variable called `label`.  This should be an array of strings.

For example:

```js
labels: ['Italy', 'India', 'Japan', 'USA']
```

You could set this array to your `label` variable, wherever it is defined:

```js
const label = ['Italy', 'India', 'Japan', 'USA'];

{
  ...
  labels: label
}
```

Comment: Iam iam passing in the labels. But the label only shows when i hover over the "pie slices"

Comment: Simple test: did you replace `labels: label` with `labels: ['Italy', 'India', 'Japan', 'USA']` What happened?  Nothing else is required to show the labels, it's the default config.

Comment: oh my bad accidentaly changed edited your answer

Comment: No worries, I handled it.  I see your edit, but I was asking about the chart config, to see what all the settings are.

Comment: You mean the values of data and labels? The data variable is just an array of ints and the labels is array of strings. nothing more

Comment: Proof:  https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-snow-rdnbl

Comment: i will compare my version to yours later tonight and get back to you, not infront of my computer right now. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have another question. Is there a possibility to add an click event to every piece of the pie. Like if i click on "italy". Then some event is triggered

Comment: Yeah, you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Template contain chart tag

```
  <chartjs-pie :labels="labels" :data="dataset" :bind="true"></chartjs-pie>
```

Then pass data through script

```
data: function data() {
          return {
            labels: ['Italy', 'India', 'Japan', 'USA'],
            dataset: [..]
          };
        },
```